# What is the source of images in MS COCO dataset?

Tags: mscoco

What is the source of images in the MS COCO dataset? Was it manually photographed for the very purpose of creating a dataset through some group of people? or crawled the web? or some image hosting site?

Anybody know?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are scraped from Flickr. See the [Terms of Use](https://cocodataset.org/#termsofuse)

> The COCO Consortium does not own the copyright of the images. Use of the images must abide by the Flickr Terms of Use.